# Track public git projects locally

Tags: git, version-control, open-source, redmine

What is the best strategy for tracking along with a public project that you are making local changes to?
I want to be able to put the public version on a private server, so that my devs can pull it from that server. To that end, I created a bare repository on my server, cloned the project from the internet to my dev box, then created a new remote, and pushed it to my local server. Is this an appropriate way to allow my devs to pull the source version from our private server?

I was hoping to make this project integrate into redmine as well, so it'd be nice to be able to see the previous changesets and commit comments, but so far I havent been able to get that to work. Redmine returns some HTTP 500 errror when trying to access the repository on my local server.

Answer (score 0):

The approach with repo sounds good.

Maybe also try to agree on some policy to only use feature branches when changing the original code, so you can keep tracking the progress of the original public repository in master branch (just a general idea, branch names could differ per-project).

I think the 500-error is Redmine specific.